# Imagem em ListTile - Flutter

Tags: lista, listview, flutter

Não estou conseguindo deixar minha imagem na minha ListTile, quando tento dimensionar a mesma só vai para horizontal e nunca na vertical, exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código, estou tentando dimensionar com a propriedade radius:

```
ListView.separated(
    separatorBuilder: (context,index) => Divider(
      color: Colors.black),
  itemCount: _professionals.length,
  itemBuilder: (context,index){
    return 
    ListTile(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      leading:  
      CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: AssetImage("images/perfil_anhan.jpg"),
        radius: 70,
      ),
      title: (Text(getName(_professionals[index]))),

      ...
```

Como poderia deixar ela proporcional?

Comment: Tente utilizar o atributo `child` do `CircleAvatar` ao invés do `backgroundImage`. Dentro do `child` utilize o `Image.asset()` e nele preencha a propriedade `fit` que é utilizada para ajustar as imagens dentro dos seus recipientes. Exemplo: `CircleAvatar(child: Image.asset("name", fit: BoxFit.contain,),);`

Comment: Olá Matheus, não consegui resolver desta forma, porém me deu uma luz e consegui resolver de outra maneira. Já vou colocar abaixo, obrigado!

Comment: Állan, nenhuma resposta atendeu sua necessidade? caso não, explique melhor o que precisa para que possamos resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, resolvi usando a propriedade child, e dentro dele um Container com borderRadius para definir o tamanho.

Segue abaixo solução:

```
                child: Container(
                    width: 100.0,
                    height: 100.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('images/hacker.jpeg'),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover),
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(75.0)),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(blurRadius: 7.0, color: Colors.black)
                        ]),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria o `CircleAvatar`, em vista da imagem que passou, e como já comentaram.

#### Exemplo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade800,
            child: Text('AH'),
          ),
          title: Text('Fulano'),
          subtitle: Text('da Silva'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://imagens.canaltech.com.br/empresas/690.400.jpg'),
          ),
          title: Text('Ciclano'),
          subtitle: Text('de Jesus'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

1º usando cor no fundo e texto.

2º usando imagem.

---

#### Resultado

[image: img]

---

Documentação oficial: [CircleAvatar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html)